# Python OpenCV distorted stitched image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Firstly, I would like to say I am new to computer vision and python in general. I am trying to stitch two images together to create one unified one. I have followed several guides online and I decided to use the ORB keypoint/feature descriptor, BF matcher to match them, and applying the ratio test to see there are good matches. I have successfully stitched one set of images, but in this dataset, I am running into problems with distortion on the second image after stitching. Like so, https://i.stack.imgur.com/b58rR.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcuE7.jpg. The code for the stitching script is as follows. (I used this guide https://towardsdatascience.com/image-stitching-using-opencv-817779c86a83) With a few modifications mine looks like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

os.chdir('images/10 meters')
img_ = cv2.imread('Output2.jpg', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.imread('DJI_0014.jpg', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)



#Setting up orb key point detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

#using orb to compute keypoints and descriptors
kp, des = orb.detectAndCompute(img_, None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
print(len(kp))
print(len(kp2))

#Setting up BFmatcher
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=False)
matches = bf.knnMatch(des, des2, k=2) #Find 2 best matches for each descriptors (This is required for ratio test?)

#Using lowes ratio test as suggested in paper at .7-.8
good = []
for m in matches:
    if m[0].distance < .8 * m[1].distance:
        good.append(m)
matches = np.asarray(good) #matches is essentially a list of matching descriptors
print(len(matches))
#Aligning the images
if(len(matches)) >= 4:
    src = np.float32([kp[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches[:, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches[:, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    #Creating the homography and mask
    H, masked = cv2.findHomography(src, dst, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    print(H)
else:
    print("Could not find 4 good matches to find homography")

dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img_, H, (img.shape[1] + 500, img.shape[0]))
dst[0:img.shape[0], 0:img.shape[1]] = img
cv2.imwrite("Output2.jpg", dst)
```

With a few print statements this is the number of kp, kp2, matches and homography
[image]

My theory is that something is going wrong when calculating the homography since the input for `wrapPerspective` are src img, homography, and size. Is this correct in saying? If so how do I go about trying to fix this issue?

EDIT: These are the input images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxGUc.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qjMe.jpg

Comment: You need to correct the barrel distortion first before registration and stitching. See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html

Comment: Would that cause the "smear" stitch? I don't see how the image being distorted would cause this issue due to the pixels being translated and not filtered

Comment: The barrel distortion causes the curving so that the stitched result does not look good. Each image is bulging/curved. Do you not want to make the buildings look "straight"?